# How to solve "The clean up '<cleanUpName>' contributed by '<plugin>' has been disabled because it does not honor any options."?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I'm creating an after save action for the java editor following [this guide](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_contributing_a_cleanup.htm). So far my code for the cleanup looks like this:

```
public class CheckFileCleanUp implements ICleanUp {

    @Override
    public ICleanUpFix createFix(final CleanUpContext cleanUpContext) throws CoreException {

        final ICompilationUnit compilationUnit = cleanUpContext.getCompilationUnit();
        IPath path = compilationUnit.getPath();
        IFile[] files = compilationUnit.getJavaProject().getProject().getWorkspace().getRoot().findFilesForLocation(path);
        RunCheckstyleOnFilesJob job = new RunCheckstyleOnFilesJob(Arrays.asList(files));
        job.setRule(job);
        job.schedule();
        return new ICleanUpFix() {
            @Override
            public CompilationUnitChange createChange(final IProgressMonitor progressMonitor) throws CoreException {
                return new CompilationUnitChange("", compilationUnit);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public CleanUpRequirements getRequirements() {
        return new CleanUpRequirements(false, false, true, Collections.<String, String> emptyMap());
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getStepDescriptions() {
        return new String[] { "Run checkstyle" };
    }

    @Override
    public void setOptions(final CleanUpOptions cleanUpOptions) {
    }

    public RefactoringStatus checkPreConditions(final IJavaProject paramIJavaProject, final ICompilationUnit[] paramArrayOfICompilationUnit,
            final IProgressMonitor paramIProgressMonitor) throws CoreException {
        return new RefactoringStatus();
    }

    public RefactoringStatus checkPostConditions(final IProgressMonitor paramIProgressMonitor) throws CoreException {
        return new RefactoringStatus();
    }
}
```

and the extension config is:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.cleanUps">
    <cleanUp id="eclipsecs.saveaction" class="eclipsecs.saveaction.CheckFileCleanUp" />
</extension>
```

The cleanup doesn't need any other options so I skipped those sections of the guide.

However the first time I simply edit a java source file and save it, I get the following message in the error log:

> The clean up 'eclipsecs.saveaction' contributed by
>   'eclipse-cs-save-action' has been disabled because it does not honor
>   any options.

How can I make my clean up honor the required options and what options are those required options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this message because you are not honoring the enabled option for your cleanup.

You must remember the `CleanUpOptions` given to you by `setOption` and test `isEnabled("your id")` in `getStepDescriptions`, `createFix`, ... and not do anything if your cleanup is not enabled.